# How to Show and hide form fields based on a selection from a dropdown menu in Django

Tags: javascript, django, google-app-engine

I have a question about how to conditional hide or show a field based on the selection of its parent field in Django.

**UPDATE: I am able to implement this feature this feature by defining a function in JavaScript, which has been tested with some simple HTML code. However, since my input table is created by Django, can anyone tell me how to call this function in Django 'onchange'? **

FINAL UPDATE: I think it is easier to use jQuery to do this.
[jQuery: Conditional show an element based on drop down box selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200498/jquery-conditional-show-an-element-based-on-drop-down-box-selection)

Javascript: 
Explanation:
 1. Before making any choice, one can only see a drop-down menu "Application method"
 2. If one chooses "Aerial Spray" from the parent box, then a new drop down menu "Aerial Size Dist"
 3. If one chooses "Ground Spray" from the parent box, then another drop down list "Ground spray type" needs input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(obj,id1,id2) {
txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';

if ( txt.match(id1) ) {document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';}
if ( txt.match(id2) ) {document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';}
</script>

<table>
<tbody align="center">
<tr><th>Application method:</th>
<td><select onchange="display(this,'A','B')" name="method" id="id_method">
<option value="">Pick a method</option>
<option value="A">Aerial Spray</option>
<option value="B">Ground Spray</option>
</select></td></tr></tbody>

<tbody id="A" align="center" style="display: none;">
<tr><th><label for="id_aerial_size_dist">Aerial Size Dist:</label></th><td><select select name="aerial_size_dist" id="id_aerial_size_dist">
<option value="" selected="selected">Pick first</option>
<option value="A1">Very Fine to Fine</option>
<option value="A2">Fine to Medium (EFED Default)</option>
</select></td></tr>
</tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="B" align="center" style="display: none;">
<tr><th><label for="id_spray_type">Ground spray type:</label></th><td><select name="spray_type" id="id_spray_type">
<option value="B1" selected="selected">Low Boom Ground Sprayer (20 Inches or Less)</option>
<option value="B2">High Boom Ground Sprayer (20 to 50 Inches: EFED Default)</option>
</select></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**Django code, which does not work now. It needs help about all the defined function 'display'.**

**updat, after adding mark_safe, the code works.**

```
class GENEECInp(forms.Form):
    application_method = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=applicationmethod_CHOICES, initial='Aerial Spray',
                                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':mark_safe("display(this,'A','B','C','D');")})
```

Comment: It is a JavaScript thing. Look into jQuery

Comment: @icn, I am a newbie in programming... Is it possible for you to give me an example of this kind application? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some custom javascript to hide or unhide the appropriate field.  Do you have any javascript in this widget?

Comment: I think the only javascript I got is the 'onchange' stuff. So should I look at Django media class?

Comment: I didn't read that properly.  You can do what you're doing by setting onchange, but I don't think that's valid javascript.  For example, your size field probably shows up as id_size in the actual rendered HTML.  I've done my javascript as separate javascript files included using media classes.  You can do it your way, but make sure your javascript is correct.

Comment: I am able to fulfill this feature by defining a function using JavaScript, but do you know how to call this function in Django form? Please see the updated post.

Comment: getting closer, still a lot of problems.  1. in your python code, you have 'display(this,'A','B','C','D');''.  A/B/C/D end up being unquoted.  You might consider 'display(this,"A","B","C","D");'.

Comment: Finally, find a way to delivery this function. widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':mark_safe("display(this,'A','B','C','D');")} However, it seems like jQuery would be a better solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200498/jquery-conditional-show-an-element-based-on-drop-down-box-selection