# How to set values for select box or drop down list box as the previous list box value is set

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use jquery to change second select list based on first select list option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-second-select-list-based-on-first-select-list-option)

I've got two select elements in my code. One for states (#us_state) and second for cities (#city_name). When I choose a "state" the second select element must contain only that cities which exists in selected state.

Comment: Do you have some sort of data source to fill both selects? Also, as always, your current code would help...either posted here or through a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery `append` to append the option values (also remember to clear the options outside the iterating loop using

`$('#city_name').html("");`

```
$('#city_name').append('<option value="'+city+'">'+city+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
var data = {
    "State 1": ["City 1", "City 2"],
    "State 2": ["City 3", "City 4"],
    "State 3": ["City 5", "City 6", "City 7"]
};

var $states = $("#us_state").on("change", function() {
    var $cities = $.map(data[this.value], function(city) {
        return $("<option />").text(city);
    });
    $("#city_name").empty().append($cities);
});

for (var state in data) {
    $("<option />").text(state).appendTo($states);
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8hbcP/