# Select specific rows based on another column's previously selected value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've looked all over but can't find anything similar to my question.

I have a table like this:

```
Fleet Name | Vehicle Reg
    xxx    |     w
    xxx    |     x
    yyy    |     y
    yyy    |     z
```

I've made a dropdown/select which shows xxx & yyy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fleet_name FROM eco_drive_table
```

Now I want to make another dropdown/select which will only show w & x when xxx selected and only show y & z when yyy is selected and then output the vehicle reg as a string

Hope that makes sense,

I'm using PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option

Answer (score 1):

Store the value from the xxx and yyy into a variable.
Than query using the WHERE condition;

```
SELECT * FROM eco_drive_table WHERE fleet_name='$variavle';
```

So when the user select xxx $variable is xxx, when select yyy $variable is yyy

Comment: ok makes sesne but how do I store the xxx and yyy's value into a variable? this is what the code is now:

   <?php
// connect to MySQL
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT fleet_name FROM eco_drive_table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<option>{$row['fleet_name']}</option>";
}
?></select>

Comment: <?php

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT fleet_name FROM eco_drive_table";
$query = mysql_query($sql,$your_connection_variable);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
 $row['fleet_name'];
 $fleet_name = $row['fleet_name']; 
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM eco_drive_table WHERE fleet_name='$fleet_name'";
$query = mysql_query($sql,$your_connection_variable);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
 echo "<option>{$row['vehicle_reg']}</option>"; 
} 
?>

Comment: <?php $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT fleet_name FROM eco_drive_table"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql); 
echo "<p> Select Fleet Name: <select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ echo "<option>{$row['fleet_name']}</option>"; $fleet_name = $row['fleet_name']; } 
echo "</select></p>";
$sql = "SELECT vehicle_registration_number FROM eco_drive_table WHERE fleet_name='$fleet_name'"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql); 
echo "<p> Select Vehicle Registration: <select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ echo "<option>{$row['vehicle_registration_number']}</option>"; } 
echo "</select></p>";
?>

Comment: thats the code i've got now but the second select option is pulling out two random vehicle regs and doesn't respond to the first select box, thanks for your help so far!