# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string error in my JavaScript and I honestly can't figure out what's wrong with the code.  I have looked at the similar questions, but I'm unable to find a solution.  The error is coming in the line highlighted with an asterisk below.

```
$("#items1").change(function () {
    if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#items2 option').clone());
    }
    var checkval = $(this).val();
/* this line: */ var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value='"+ checkval +"']');
    $('#items2').html(options);
});
```

The code is taken from [Use jQuery to change a second select list based on the first select list option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option)

I've added the extra quotes around the checkval to get rid of another error, this might be the problem, but if I change it, the other error returns.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. `checkVal` looks like a string, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value="' + checkval + '"]');
```

The double quotes need to be inside the single quotes.

Comment: @user3463538 If the answer helps you check the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is this:

```
'[value=' "+ checkval +"']'
^       ^ ^            ^^
1       2 3            45
```

At 1, you're starting a string; at 2, you're ending it. That means when we reach 3, the start of a new string using double quotes, it's an unexpected string.

You probably want:

```
'[value="' + checkval + '"]'
^       ^^              ^^ ^
1       23              45 6
```

At 1, we start the string. 2 is just a `"` within the string, it doesn't end it. 3 ends it, then we append `checkval`, then we start a new string (4) with a `"` in it (5) followed by a `]` and then the end of the string (6).

Answer (score 3):

```
'[value=' "+ checkval +"']'
```

should be

```
'[value="' + checkval + '"]'
```

You have the quotations in the wrong place, so the double-quotation mark is not being included in your string.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to escape the quotations with a backslash (you have to escape this backslash too,  because backslashes do have a special meaning inside of strings) -> use \\ in front of the quotations.  But notice that quotations aren't required in every case.