# Change second select list based on first select list value in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Updated with answer code at bottom**

For second select box, show select options for only those `staff members` associated to the selected `team`.

**Form:**

[image]

---

**Example case**: A user selects another team. The staff member select options updates to display only those staff members associated with that selected team.

[image]

I know the solution is with javascript, but I'm having trouble applying it within a rails environment. I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option) but am still having trouble applying it to my rails app.

---

**Code**

```
#app/controllers/task_notes_controller.rb
...
def new
  @task_note = TaskNote.new
  @teams = Team.all.includes(:staff_members)
end
...
```

```
#app/views/task_notes/_form.html.erb
...
<%= select_tag('team', options_from_collection_for_select(@teams, :id, :name ) ) %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :staff_member_id %><br>
  # Currently displays all staff members on every team, no matter what team is selected.
  <%= f.collection_select :staff_member_id, StaffMember.all, :id, :first_name %>
</div>
...
```

```
#app/assets/javascripts/task_notes.js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#team").on('change', function(){
      alert("The new team id is: " + $(this).val() ); 
      # The value (the id of the team) does update on selection option change.  
      # Now I need to specify that I want the select options for the staff members
      # select box to update and show only staff members with this team_id 
  });

});
```

Comment: hi i just ran into the same problem, can u also share the JSON file structure?

Comment: @tmvnty what do you mean the JSON file structure?

Comment: where did you store the list of team id and staff members? I thought you used JSON to do that, sry I'm still a learner.

Comment: No problem.  The JSON request passes through the `routes.rb` file which shoots the request over to `#app/controllers/task_notes_controller.rb` for processing.  That is where it grabs and stores all the `staff_member` records. The select box within the view updates with the code specified in `#app/assets/javascripts/task_notes.js`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you fire an `ajax` call to your `controller`. (Keep in mind that this `url` from the `ajax` call must exist in your routes).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#team").on('change', function(){
    $ajax({
      url: "populate_other_list",
      type: "GET",
      data: {team_id: $(this).val()},
      // Callbacks that will be explained
    })
  });
```

Next you make your `action` inside your `controller`.

```
def populate_other_list
  team_id = params[:team_id]
  @staff = Staff.find_by team_id: team_id
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @staff }
  end
end
```

With this, on your `success` callback of your `ajax` call, you get a `JSON` object with your list. So you need to clear the `staff` select and create the options and append to it.

```
// Ajax call
success: function(data) {
  $("#staff_member_id").children().remove();
  // Create options and append to the list
}
// Rest of Ajax call
```

As you can see, i didn't put the code that create the options and put them inside the list, but a simple search will have plenty of results about this. The idea is simple though.

Comment: Those who are wondering to create options:
var listitems = [];
$.each(data,function(key, value) 
{
       listitems += '<option value="' + key+ '">' + value + '</option>';
});

$("#select").append(listitems);