# Ajax call not working for dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have successfully done ajax calls before for situations like this in a form:

- User selects a 'category' from a list in a select box. Ajax is fired off when selection is made, which updates a *second* select box with all items related to the selected category.

I know how to successfully do that thanks to the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612461/change-second-select-list-based-on-first-select-list-value-in-rails).

What I am now doing is dynamically adding new nested form fields with the [nested_form_fields gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_form_fields). Here is a snapshot:

[image]

So every time the user selects "Add Service", the `nested_form_fields` gem generates a new nested form with two select boxes (a `service category` select box and a `service provided` select box as pictured above).

It works fine.  The issue I am having is firing off an ajax request for this dynamic content when the user chooses a `service category`.

When a user selects a `service category`, I want to send an ajax call, which updates that second select box with all the services related to that `service category`.

The issue is that the ajax request is not firing off at all.  The server is not getting any requests when the user selects a `service category`.  I think the issue is that since these nested fields are generated dynamically, the javascript does not have the opportunity to bind the ajax request to the new nested fields' `service category` select box.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#service_category_selection").on('change', function(){
           $.ajax({
               url: "narrow_service_by_service_category_selection",
               type: "GET",
               data: {service_category_id: $(this).val()},
               success: function(data){
                   /* ... */
               }
           })
    });

});
```

I think if I was somehow able to make this javascript run every time the html in the page changed (ex: when new nested form fields are added), then the javascript will able to bind that ajax call to the new `service category` select box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well only one element can have the id, so you need to reference it with a class. event delegation will capture the new elements. Since you did not give HTML structure, I had to keep the answer for finding the second select generic.

```
$(document).on("change", ".service_category_selection", function () {
    var select = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "narrow_service_by_service_category_selection",
        type: "GET",
        data: {service_category_id: $(this).val()},
        success: function (data) {
            var secondSelect = select.closest("parentElementSelector").find(".classForNextSelect");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: should probably be `$(".service_category_selection")` since it is now a class?

Comment: whoops, bad copy and paste there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a delegated event handler instead of a direct one. Just change

```
$("#service_category_selection").on('change', function...
```

to

```
$('body').on('change', '#service_category_selection', function...
```

You can read more about this in the jQuery docs here:

https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

HTH!