# JavaScript dependent

Tags: javascript

I have two drop downs dependent on each other.

When I'm selecting the FRUIT, I want to show only one Apple value from select2 and hide all the others but when I'm selecting Animal I want to show all the values
Please help me write the Javascript `function`.

Thanks.

```
 <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2">Fox</option>
    <option value="2">Bear</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>



 //This is my java script function

        function display(){
                                var access=document.getElementById("select1");
                                var list = document.getElementById("select2");
                                var selectlist=access[access.selectedIndex].value;

                                    if(selectlist="APPLE"){
                            list.style.visiblity="hidden";
                                            }else{
                                        list.style.visiblity="block";
                                    }
```

Comment: what about that `td>` ?

Comment: It is<td> and after <select id="state" name="state" class="selectBox"> it is <c:forEach var="stateLevel" items="${stateForm.stateList}">>plz ignore my english it is not good.

Comment: That might be a simple typo seeing that `td>` .. plus what is your question? It is very vague what you are asking for. Also, are you using `angularjs`?

Comment: No I am not using angular js nor J Query.it is plain java script.I have two dropdowns and after selecting one selected value from the first dropdown i need to display only one value  from five values in the second dropdown and hide all the four values.Again If i am selecting as second value from first dropdown this time it should not restrict to one value and should display all the values.

Comment: Edit your code please. What do you get right now?

Comment: On the selected value of first dropdown it is showing all the values in second drop down.It is not hiding the values in the second drop down

Comment: Very confused what these `${stateLevel.value}` and so on do.. maybe check this, i cannot look into your code enought to help you just now, but this should help: [Use jQuery to change a second select list based on the first select list option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/auwaauwy/)

```js
//Add eventlistener for change-event
document.getElementById("selCategory").addEventListener("change", filter, false);

//Filter function which will filter on selected value from first select.
function filter()
{
 var cat = document.getElementById("selCategory");
  var opt = document.getElementById("selOptions");
  var selectedValue = cat.options[cat.selectedIndex].value;
  var firstEl = false;
  var firstIndex = 0;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < opt.options.length; i++)
  {
   if(opt.options[i].value !== selectedValue)
    {
     opt.options[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    else
    {
     opt.options[i].style.display = "block";
      if(!firstEl)
      {
       firstIndex = i;
        firstEl = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  opt.value = opt.options[firstIndex].value;
}

//Execute on first load, second select is filtered from the start.
filter();
```

```html
<select name="category" id="selCategory">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Bird</option>
  <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="options" id="selOptions">
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2">Fox</option>
    <option value="2">Bear</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't know how or why you would restrict the first option to only "Apple" because that would mean you'd have to hardcode it. But it wouldn't be impossible, but this code could give you a headstart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The values is coming from back end.Let me put this way .Let say.<option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Fruit2</option>
  <option value="3">Fruit3</option>
  <option value="4">Fruit4</option> and the for 'FRUIT' i want to show apple but for "Fruit2".I want to show Banana,Apple,Orange..I know it is a bit vauge but i hope you could understand.

Comment: The problem is that you only have 1 option `Fruit`and the options `Banana, Apple, Orange` have their value set at the value of `Fruit` (meaning they are linked to that one option). If you want to show `Apple`when you select `Fruit`, you will have to change the values of `Banana`and `Orange` so they won't be linked to `Fruit`anymore. That's what I'm understanding from your question. Otherwise you would have to use 3 `<select>` elements, filtering each other.

Comment: If I have two option Fruit and Fruit1 and the options Banana, Apple, Orange have their value set at both the value of Fruit and Fruit1.Now can i hide the value of  Banana,Orange and show only Apple for Fruit.But For Fruit1 I want to show all the value( Banana,Orange and Apple).IS there any way we can achive this through plain java script.

Comment: Not that I can think of at this particular moment. There might be a workaround, but I cannot think of one right now.

Comment: If you could find a solution .I will be very thankful of you.