# change option value based on other dropdown PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 simple dropdown list that if city dropdown selected have value "Balikpapan" its display specific option on service dropdown then if not its display other option :

here's my function code :

```
function Kurir(){
    var kota = $('select[name="descity"] option:selected').text();
    kurir ='';
    kurir2='';
    if (kota == Balikpapan){
        kurir = '<option selected="true" style="display:none;">Pilih Kurir</option><option value="Kurir dalam Kota">Kurir dalam Kota</option>';
        $('#service').html(kurir);
    else
        kurir2 = '<option selected="true" style="display:none;">Pilih Kurir</option><option value="">Pilih Kurir</option><option value="jne">JNE</option><option value="pos">POS</option><option value="tiki">TIKI</option>';
        $('#service').html(kurir2); 
    }
}
```

and here's my dropdown code

```
<td><label for="kota">Kota</label></td>
                  <td><select id="descity" onchange="kurir();" class="" name="">
                     <option value="">Pilih Kurir</option>
                     <option value="Balikpapan">Balikpapan</option>
                     <option value="Malang">Malang</option>
                     <option value="Surabaya">Surabaya</option>
                  </select> 

<td><label for="Kurir">Kurir</label></td>
                  <td><select id="service" onchange="DestVal();PostProvCity();" class="" name="">
                     <option value="">Pilih Kurir</option>
                     <option value="jne">JNE</option>
                     <option value="pos">POS</option>
                     <option value="tiki">TIKI</option>
                  </select>
```

Comment: this $('select[name="descity"] option:selected') selector won't match anything in that html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to change a second select list based on the first select list option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option)

Comment: @flauntster ah sry the value is postcity, typo on question sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another option to display dropdown services as mentioned below. You can use ajax throw display content.

1. Test.php

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("select.country").change(function(){
               var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "process-request.php",
                   data: { country : selectedCountry } 
               }).done(function(data){
                   $("#response").html(data);
               });
           });
       });
   </script>

   </head>
   <body>
       <form>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <label>Country:</label>
                           <select class="country">
                               <option>Select</option>
                               <option value="usa">United States</option>
                               <option value="india">India</option>
                               <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                           </select>
                   </td>
                   <td id="response"></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
        </form>
   </body> 
   </html>
   ```
2. process-request.php

   ```
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST["country"])){
   $country = $_POST["country"];
   $countryArr = array("usa" => array("New Yourk", "Los Angeles", "California"),
                       "india" => array("Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"),
                       "uk" => array("London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"));
   if($country !== 'Select'){
           echo "<label>Services:</label>";
           echo "<select>";
           foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
               echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
           }
           echo "</select>";
       } 
   }
   ?>
   ```

Let me know if any query for the same.

Comment: thx for this solution, Never thinking this way tho..

thx rly much :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a small modification to AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd answer:

before the ajax function its worth deleting any  tags if already present based on a previous selection so this way anytime the user makes a selection, the new results doesn't add to the previous list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        $("#response option").remove(); // add this line
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process-request.php",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```