# dropdown selected option picks option in another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am looking how to have it when i pick volvo option then the 740 is selected. i want to add other if statements but i cant not figure this out. if i pick saab i want it to select 240

I would like to use jquery or javascript

Thank you in advance. This is what i have and it does not work.

Below is the corrected code to change the drop downs.

```
<select id="myselect1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="myselectVolvo">
  <option value="740">740</option>
  <option value="940">940</option>
  <option value="240">240</option>
  <option value="340">340</option>
</select>



$('#myselect1').change(function(){


        if($('#myselect1').val() == 'volvo'){ 

        $('#myselectVolvo').val('940').trigger('change');}

       else if($('#myselect1').val() == 'saab'){
           $('#myselectVolvo').val('240').trigger('change'); }




    //alert("The text has been changed.");}
  //};
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to change a second select list based on the first select list option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option)

Comment: condition in `if` is wrong you need to use `$('#myselect1').val() == 'volvo'`. You missed `.val()` after jquery selector.

Comment: Also you need to consider @Bobbey's answer and correct typo mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the last js code line. 
`#myselctVolvo` should be `#myselectVolvo`

> your condition in if is wrong you need to use $('#myselect1').val() == 'volvo'. You
>   missed .val() after jquery selector.

Comment: +1. Thats a good catch, Still his condition in `if` is wrong. You can check that in my comment and update your answer.

Comment: Odd. i made the changes you said to do bobbey and still have an issue. could you do a fiddle ? Can you add saab too. The real issue will have more than two if statements

Comment: Describe your issue please.

Comment: after making the changes I still can not select volvo and it change to 940. I was hoping to do that and then if i chose saab it changes to 240

Comment: Please update the code in your question which produces said issue.

Comment: updated code to correct edits. If i put an alert after it then the drop down changes. But without the alert then it stays the same.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I will update the code at top. I forgot the trigger. I feel silly