# Populated Select with html + JS

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have this Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Ardee12/tL643rjq/3/
My problem is, I always get the same options at the third select from second select (vice versa), after I select an option from the first one. I need to stick for their own option (second and third select), but still have the populated function from their "rel" attribute. Can anyone please help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".mainSelect").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('.kidSelect option').clone());
    }
    var rel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel');
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[rel=' + rel + ']');
    $('.kidSelect').html(options);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mainSelect">
  <option rel="1">Fruit</option>
  <option rel="2">Animal</option>
  <option rel="3">Bird</option>
  <option rel="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select class="kidSelect">
  <option rel="1">Banana</option>
  <option rel="1">Apple</option>
  <option rel="1">Orange</option>
  <option rel="2">Wolf</option>
  <option rel="2">Fox</option>
  <option rel="2">Bear</option>
  <option rel="3">Eagle</option>
  <option rel="3">Hawk</option>
  <option rel="4">BWM</option>
</select>

<select class="kidSelect">
  <option rel="1">AAAAA</option>
  <option rel="2">BBBBB</option>
  <option rel="3">CCCCC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat each of the kidSelect individually. Loop through each of them at the beginning and store a clone of their own options in each instance.

Then when you change main select, filter each set separately

```js
  // store a clone of each kidSelect options on page load
  $('.kidSelect').each(function() {
    $(this).data('options', $(this).children().clone());
  });

  $(".mainSelect").change(function() {

    var rel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel');

    // filter each kids options and set in place
    $('.kidSelect').html(function() {
      return $(this).data('options').filter('[rel=' + rel + ']').clone();          
    });
      // trigger the change on page load also to do initial filtering
  }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mainSelect">
  <option rel="1">Fruit</option>
  <option rel="2">Animal</option>
  <option rel="3">Bird</option>
  <option rel="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select class="kidSelect">
  <option rel="1">Banana</option>
  <option rel="1">Apple</option>
  <option rel="1">Orange</option>
  <option rel="2">Wolf</option>
  <option rel="2">Fox</option>
  <option rel="2">Bear</option>
  <option rel="3">Eagle</option>
  <option rel="3">Hawk</option>
  <option rel="4">BWM</option>
</select>

<select class="kidSelect">
  <option rel="1">AAAAA</option>
  <option rel="2">BBBBB</option>
  <option rel="3">CCCCC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but here is a guess.

I think you only want to effect the second select with the changes. For that you need to adjust your selector. It currently selects both selects.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".mainSelect").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('.js-kidSelect option').clone());
    }
    var rel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel');
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[rel=' + rel + ']');
    $('.js-kidSelect').html(options);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mainSelect">
  <option rel="1">Fruit</option>
  <option rel="2">Animal</option>
  <option rel="3">Bird</option>
  <option rel="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select class="kidSelect js-kidSelect">
  <option rel="1">Banana</option>
  <option rel="1">Apple</option>
  <option rel="1">Orange</option>
  <option rel="2">Wolf</option>
  <option rel="2">Fox</option>
  <option rel="2">Bear</option>
  <option rel="3">Eagle</option>
  <option rel="3">Hawk</option>
  <option rel="4">BWM</option>
</select>

<select class="kidSelect">
  <option rel="1">AAAAA</option>
  <option rel="2">BBBBB</option>
  <option rel="3">CCCCC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It almost work as I expected. But I needed like this. When I selected "fruit" at first select, the second select should only display "banana, apple and orange" and the third select should only display "AAAAA" ... please help me