# WooCommerce - how do I disable attribute option menus until the one above is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

On the Product page of a Variable Product, I'd like to use javascript/jQuery to control the attribute drop down menus.

Basically, I want Option Menu 2 to be selectable *only when* the user has already selected an option from Option Menu 1

*Example:*

**My Variable Product**

- Platform: Option Menu 1 (user must select platform, Mac|PC, for example, before they can proceed to...)
- Version: Option Menu 2 (Full Version | Upgrade for example. Must be selected before...)
- Shipping: Option Menu 3 (Boxed | Download)

If someone could even point me to the correct way to access these Option Menus with javascript/jQuery, I could try to take it from there.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to add customized template in theme folder, and use some of the solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200498/jquery-conditional-show-an-element-based-on-drop-down-box-selection

Comment: Thanks Michal S - Will try it and post results next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked this out...

You need to copy: '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php'

to: '/wp-content/themes/my_theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php'

That's the file that generates the Select menus for Variable Product attributes, so you're creating a version to edit for your theme.

After the `</form>` on approx. line 107 add the following:

```
<!-- MySite Menu Additions -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if ( ! empty( $available_variations ) ) { ?>

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            <?php
                $loop = 0;
                foreach ( $attributes as $name => $options ) {
                $loop++;
            ?>
                $(function() {
                    $( "#<?php echo $name ?>" ).change(function() {
                        if ($(this).val() != "") { // Because "Choose an option..." has a value of ''
                            $(this).closest( 'tr' ).next().find( '.value-variable' ).prop( "disabled", false );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(this).closest( 'tr' ).nextAll().find( '.value-variable' ).prop( "disabled", true );
                            $(this).closest( 'tr' ).nextAll().find( '.value-variable' ).val( "" );

                        }
                    });
                });

            <?php } //End foreach ?>

        });

    <?php } ?>

    </script>
<!-- End: MySite Menu Additions -->
```

That works for me. Hope it helps someone.

I got additional help on this here (might also be useful):

[Enable Sequential Select Menus when you don't know the IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022039/enable-sequential-select-menus-when-you-dont-know-the-ids)