# Enable Sequential Select Menus when you don't know the IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I have a set of Select Menus that are built from the variants in a product database (WooCommerce). There can be any number of them, usually from 3 to 8. Something simple like:

```
<select id="*Could be Anything*" name="*Could be Anything*">
    <option>Choose an option...</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<select id="*Could be Anything*" name="*Could be Anything*" disabled="true">
    <option>Choose an option...</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<select id="*Could be Anything*" name="*Could be Anything*" disabled="true">
    <option>Choose an option...</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to enable them sequentially based on a selection being made in the previous menu. I don't need to change any options in the new menu - I just need to enable it.

So, *if Select1 ≠ "Choose an option..." then enable Select2 and if Select2 ≠ "Choose an option..." then enable Select3.*

The problem is I can't predict what the IDs are going to be, so I can't use a variant of:

```
$(function() {
    $("#theID").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "Choose an option…") {
            $("#theID_2").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else
            $("#theID_2").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

My question then: is there a way to sequence the enabling/disabling of Select menus using jQuery alone without knowing the ids in advance?

Is this just a crazy idea? Would I be better to try to build the javascript on the fly, reading the ids are they're written into the Selects server-side?

Comment: Are they the only selects on the page?

Comment: No, there will be other Selects in the sidebar, but the Selects I'm working on are wrapped in a predictable div#id. But I think Khôi's answer might do it (below). Going to try it now.

Answer (score 1):

If the selects are in a sequential order to each other, you might be able to use JQuery.next():

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$("select").on('change', function(){
    $(this).next("select").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zv72Y/

Answer (score 1):

If all these selects in one containers, then you can attach an event listener to each, which will unlock next select element:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <select id="*Could be Anything*" name="*Could be Anything*">
        <option>Choose an option...</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="*Could be Anything*" name="*Could be Anything*" disabled="true">
        <option>Choose an option...</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="*Could be Anything*" name="*Could be Anything*" disabled="true">
        <option>Choose an option...</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascipt:

```
$('.container').on('change','select', function(){    
    $(this).nextAll('select').first().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

[`$().nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) - Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) will select first select after current and remove from him attritbute `disabled`.

[Example: jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2avKp/)

Comment: Both answers above work great. I realized, however, I was going to need to speak to the WooCommerce IDs in other ways too, so I took what I learned from the above and managed to answer a question that has had me stumped for a while - "WooCommerce - how do I disable attribute option menus until the one above is selected?" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080663/woocommerce-how-do-i-disable-attribute-option-menus-until-the-one-above-is-sel -