# Conditional JQuery show choice based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress and woocommerce to build my site and have an issue with the woocommerce variable products.

I only want to show an option once a previous options has been selected.

I found this thread ([jQuery: Conditional show an element based on drop down box selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200498/jquery-conditional-show-an-element-based-on-drop-down-box-selection)) which explained the JQuery I needed to complete the process and I have adapted the code to fit with my selection and got it working here on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ASJu/61/). So I know the code works.

The HTML code is:

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            <label for="pa_slat-material">Slat Material</label>
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            <select id="pa_slat-material" name="attribute_pa_slat-material">
                <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
                <option value="treated-redwood" class="active">Treated Redwood</option>
                <option value="douglas-fir" class="active">Douglas Fir</option>
                <option value="hardwood-iroko" class="active">Hardwood Iroko</option>
                <option value="recycled-plastic" class="active">Recycled Plastic</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            <label for="pa_rp-colour">Recycled Plastic Colour</label>
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            <select id="pa_rp-colour" name="attribute_pa_rp-colour">
                <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
                <option value="black" class="active">Black</option>
                <option value="grey" class="active">Grey</option>
                <option value="brown" class="active">Brown</option>
                <option value="green" class="active">Green</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and the JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $recycledplasticTr = $('#pa_rp-colour').closest('tr').hide();

$('#pa_slat-material').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if (selectedValue === 'recycled-plastic') {
        $recycledplasticTr.show();
    } else {
        $recycledplasticTr.hide();
    }
});
});
```

But now I have no idea where to put it in order to make it happen on my site?
Can I add it to the functions.php?

**OR**

Do I need to add it directly to the template page which deals with this form?

I can feel I am close but missing something simple to someone else but not to me.

Comment: You included the jquery library in your page?

Comment: There is other JS used in the page and the site @Rohit So I am assuming there is. Do I have to add to it or adapt it to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new scripts.js file add below code in that file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $recycledplasticTr = $('#pa_rp-colour').closest('tr').hide();

    $('#pa_slat-material').change(function () {
       var selectedValue = $(this).val();

       if (selectedValue === 'recycled-plastic') {
           $recycledplasticTr.show();
       } else {
           $recycledplasticTr.hide();
       }
    });

    //any other jquery codes

});
```

upload this file to your theme and use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in your theme's functions.php

Comment: I have added the wp_enqueue_script to my functions php. I think it is correct. I didn't really understand it. I have the row hidden now but it doesn't appear when the condition is selected. Also It only works in the main them and not my child theme. @shubhra

Comment: I have it working in the child theme now but still the hidden row is not showing when correct item is selected... getting there.

Comment: Just noticed that even if this was working it is just hiding the option and it will still be added to the product detail when adding the item to the cart. Even if not selected. As woocommerce needs all the variables to have a option before being able to add the item to cart the hidden option needs a value to priceable. HELP.

Comment: @Crease don't know how woocommerce works. Maybe post your problem at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: They don't like to talk about anything that isn't specific to Wordpress @shubhra Woo-commerce seems to be off topic. If no one else can help then I will have to look elsewhere. I am sure there is a simple answer to this that I am missing due to a lack of knowledge.

Comment: Can you maybe update your question and tell us what exactly you need or start a new topic with appropriate tags and title?

Comment: I have found a solution using the gravity forms plugin seemed to be the easiest way to work with woocommerce. Thanks for your help.